# Is it possible to create table of content page using puppeteer and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer
I have created the pdf but i want to dynamically create table of content page based on pages in PDF.

Is it possible or this feature is in futire version of puppeteer?

Comment: There is no built in utility for this within `puppeteer`. I suggest to search for a third party module which could maybe do it? But probably it is way too hard for any third party page.

Comment: @SilvanBregy Thanks for the suggestion, I will check and try to change the current package most probably.